# Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0. Error de sintaxis

Tags: javascript, json, asincronismo

Este es el error que me dice la consola, a la hora de intentar mostrar los JSON:

> myFunction.js:17 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position
> 0.

No estoy usando ningun framework, ni ningun servidor, es todo desde html y JS vainilla.

A la linea que hace referencia es esta:

```
const res = await fetch('api.json')
```

Es la segunda vez que me ocurre este problema, a la hora de utilizar datos tipo JSON.
He probado varias opciones de otras personas que les ha ocurrido y han publicado el error en StackOverflow,
pero ninguna me funciona. Os comparto mi codigo para ver si alguien me puede ayudar.

Me salta error, en el fetch, a la hora de responder con Json.

Aqui está el codigo JS:

```
'use strcit'

const items = document.querySelector('#items');
const templateCard = document.querySelector('#template-card').content;
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    fetchData();
});

const fetchData = async () => {
    try{
        const res = await fetch('api.json')
        const data = await res.json();
        console.log(data)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
};

const printCard = data => {
    data.forEach(element => {
        templateCard.querySelector('h3').textContent = element.name;

        const clone = templateCard.cloneNode(true);
        fragment.appendChild(clone)
    })

    items.appendChild(fragment);
};
```

Aqui dejo los JSON. Están en una carpeta llamada api.json que es la que hace referencia el:

```
const res = await fetch('api.json')
```

El código html no lo dejo, ya que creo que no es util, ya que el problema viene de otro lugar.

Añado los JSON:

```
[
    {
    "precio": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Desayuno",
    "description": "Lorem"
    },
    {
    "precio": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ensalada Cesar",
    "description": "Lorem"
    }
]
```

Comment: Este error te quiere decir que hay un error de sintaxis en el JSON, añade el JSON para corroborar

Comment: Acabo de añadir los JSON al codigo, gracias por la atención

Comment: La estructura es correcta de los json, ese error viene de que a lo mejor lo estás recuperando mal

Comment: Qué aparece si ejecutas un `console.log(res.text())`?

Comment: Me mantiene el error, me sigue diciendo que error en sintaxis, gracias

Comment: Al parecer es valido. Para fines de debugueo, remplaza todo el contenido (o crea otro archivo) que contenga `{"campo":"valor"}` para descartar algún detalle en la estructura.

Comment: Me continua manteniendo el error. Hice un archivo nuevo y tambien lo intenté con el que tenia, borrando los Json que tenia, gracias

Comment: ¿Podrías indicarnos qué te muestran las DevTools del navegador como respuesta de esa petición? ¿Qué código de error te da, 2XX/4XX/5XX? ¿Ves correctamente ahí la respuesta? ¿Es posible que el servidor no te esté devolviendo una respuesta válida?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
myFunction.js:18 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen impide leer el recurso remoto en file:///c:/Users/nench/Desktop/Abraham/Git%20repositories/restaurant_app/app_restaurant-main/Restaurant%20App/template/api.json (razón: la solicitud CORS no es http).

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que es un problema de ruta, que no es capturado por `catch()` porque, según [la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch)

> El objeto Promise devuelto desde fetch() no será rechazado con un estado de error HTTP incluso si la respuesta es un error HTTP 404 o 500. En cambio, este se resolverá normalmente (con un estado ok configurado a false), y  este solo sera rechazado ante un fallo de red o si algo impidió completar la solicitud.

Entonces, antes de procesar, debes analizar el resultado:

```
const fetchData = async () => {
    try{
        const res = await fetch('api.json');
        // ¿La respuesta es correcta?
        if(res.ok) {
            // Interpretar JSON
            const data = await res.json();
            console.log(data)
        } else {
            // Hubo error, mostrar en consola
            console.log(res.status, res.statusText);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
};
```

Con esto ya te podrás dar una idea de lo que debes corregir. Lamentablemente no funciona en *fragmento de código*. Probé en *localhost* y sí funciona, mostrando en consola: `404 Not Found`.

**Actualización:**

No había notado tu comentario:

> No estoy usando ningun framework, **ni ningun servidor**, es todo desde html y JS vainilla.

Los navegadores pueden bloquear las peticiones AJAX cuando estás usando el protocolo de archivo, es decir, abriendo directamente desde su ubicación en disco y mostrando en la barra de dirección algo como `file:///ruta/archivo.html`.

Te recomiendo instalar un servidor en tu equipo, no es tan complicado y hay varias opcines, por ejemplo:

- [Web Server for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb): Es una extensión para usar en el navegador Chrome; desconozco si se pueda instalar en sus derivados (Opera, Edge, etc.).
- [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/es/index.html): Servidor web multiplataforma con: Apache, varias versiones de PHP, MySQL, MariaDB y algunos añadidos.
- [Wampserver](https://www.wampserver.com/en/): Casi lo mismo que el anterior y, aunque es un poco más complicado de configurar de acuerdo a tus preferencias, es el que más me agrada.

Comment: Te agradezco mucho las recomendaciones. Probaré a usar servidor propio, tiene pinta que van por ahi los tiros. Gracias